# How do I resize a UIScrollView so that it's not 100% of the parent UIView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiscrollview

I've built an app using the UITabBar template. I have a few tabbar items, one item displays a view. That view has a UIScrollView element that has paging enabled to mimic the behaviour of the iPhone springboard i.e. pages that can be scrolled left to right.

I'm trying to drop in a UIPageControl, so I've resize the UIScrollView so that it's slightly shorter than the parent UIView height and have placed a UIPageControl below it.

When I run the app the UIScrollView is always 100% of the height of the parent UIView and I can't see the UIPageControl.

I've got the following code in my viewDidLoad method of the view controller for the tab:

```
UIScrollView *tempScrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view;
tempScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(640,377);
```

This sets the content size ok and I can scroll left to right. I've tried adding:

```
tempScrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 377);
```

To to resize the scroll view but it still shows 100%. See diagram below showing the issue:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't resize the frame to 640, 377 because it would make the paging stop working, once the contentSize would be the same as the frame size.

One solution would be to set the desired frame size in the interface builder (like the left most figure) and set proper autosizing masks. I gues what you are looking for is the configuration below

[image: The most important part is the locked bottom margin]

To check if the changes are working, I would use a uiscrollview of height visibly smaller, just to make sure the behaviour is the desired.

Comment: I've visually resized the UIScrollView to two thirds of the height of parent view. I've set the background of the scroll view to red. I've also setup the auto sizing options as you recommended but when I run the app and switch to that tab, the UIScrollView still fills the entire view. Is the UITabBar manipulating my view somehow?

Comment: If the view is not being resized by some code instruction, I don't have any other hypothesis. Try disabling the superview's autosize subviews property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your view to scroll you need to change the `tempScrollView.contentSize` to be bigger than `tempScrollView.frame`

If you do this:

```
CGFloat contentWidth = tempScrollView.frame.size.width*2;
tempScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(contentWidth,377);
```

You will have 2 pages.

You need to activate paging too with:

```
[tempScrollView setPagingEnabled:TRUE];
```